# How to connect to jenkins installed in mac from a different system

Tags: macos, jenkins

I have installed Jenkins in mac and it can be accessed with http://localhost:8080. When I try to add a git webhook, it says 'Couldn't connect to Server'. How can GitHub connect to Jenkins installed in mac?

I have installed all the Git plugins. I have tried with github personal token and github password too.

No code involved here

I expect the github webhook to connect to jenkins server

Comment: You can't use `localhost`, it's **local** so it won't work on github. You need to use the IP address of your mac

Comment: In git webhook, I am giving http://<myip>:8080/grpbhook. The github isn't able to connect to the server.

Comment: Then it's simply the wrong address or it's not accessible. Can you access your jenkins via a web browser using this address ?

Comment: no I can't, i am not sure how can I achieve that.

Comment: Then it's a problem with your mac and his address, not Jenkins

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to configure webhook in GitHub first:

set url in configuration of webhook as follows:
 `http://YourIpAddress:8080/github-webhook/`

Now, configure jenkins as mentioned below:
Setup you **deploy keys (ssh keys)** first in GitHub and **Jenkins Credentials** and then add github project info to your project, **put ssh url of git repository** (if repository is private), select **webhook SCM hook pulling** in **Build triggers** window of the respective project and add your other settings.

Now try to run this, it should work fine if all these steps followed.

Comment: thats great...!

Answer (score 0):

Bitbucket can't connect because your localhost is not accessible from the internet.

What are you trying to use jenkins for?

Usually, you would want it to be installed on a server, not your local machine.  That way it can be accessed by other team members and other tools/services such as Github.

Comment: I am trying to use Jenkins for build and deploy of iOS code. I have a mac managed machine to which I am trying to make a dedicated Jenkins server.

Answer (score 0):

Github or Bitbucket are internet based services.

As they are hosted "outisde" your network, these services cannot reach your ip *(ie: 192.168.0.1.120)*

Depending on your internet access provider, you might have a "public" IP visible from internet.
Once you'll have it, you then need to expose your port "8080" (Jenkins one) through your firewall or router...

Please notice opening firewall to well known service port is a risk to consider.